# Two-Stage Stochastic Optimization: How to deal with Infeasible scenario while calculating EEV (Expected result of using the EV solution)

Tags: optimization, cplex, stochastic-programming

I am trying to solve some of the stochastic optimization proposed problems for an Optimization course I joined.

One of the exercices asks to solve the Expected Value problem. I already made it.

Next exercise asks to solve the expected result of using the EV solution (EEV). So I started solving the |Ω| = 2 linear problems, one for each scenario, setting the decision variables to the values ​​obtained in the optimal solution of EV.

But it turned out that one of these two problems is infeasible. So, how can I calculate the EEV in this case?

Answer (score 3):

A paper [here](https://addi.ehu.es/bitstream/handle/10810/18673/TFG_S.Laconcepcion.pdf?) speak of scenarios for EEV that are infeasible. Alternative is to use a complete recourse model, unfix stage 1 variables for the model to adapt. I guess you may experiment by making solution of the EV kind of upper/lower bounds for the stage 1 variables.